# How to send data from DialogFragment to Fragment using viewmodel

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to send data from DialogFragment to Fragment using ViewModel but it seems both fragment and Dialog fragment are referencing different instances of ViewModel. so I can't access data . Is there any way I can fix this issue? thanks

Here is my Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FragmentToReceiveData:BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_1){
   private val viewModel: AddScheduleViewModel by viewModels()
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: $viewModel")   // will print ...MyViewModel@62274cc  

      viewModel.dataFromDialog.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
         //nothing happens
      } 
   }
   .
   .
   .
   private fun openDialog(){
    val action=FragmentToReceiveDataDirections.actionFragmentToReceiveDataToExampleDialog()
    findNavController().navigate(action)
    //exampleDialog.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "alarmDialog") //same issue      
   }
   
}
```

Here is ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(){
   var dataFromDialog=MutableLiveData<SomeClass>()
   
   fun saveDataFromDialog(data:SomeClass){
     dataFromDialog.value=data      
   }
 }
```

Here is my DialogFragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ExampleDialog:DialogFragment() {
  val viewModel:MyViewModel by viewModels()
  override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog: $viewModel")   // will print ...MyViewModel@125436
    .
    .
    .
    viewMode.saveDataFromDialog(data)
  }
}
```

P.S: I'm using single activity architecture, So I'm not sure if activityViewModels() is a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to share ViewModel between fragments, you can use `activityViewModels()`. for instance,

```kotlin
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    ...
}

class MasterFragment : Fragment() {

    // Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
    // from the fragment-ktx artifact
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...
    }
}

class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    // Use the 'by activityViewModels()' Kotlin property delegate
    // from the fragment-ktx artifact
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...
    }
}
```

please read more in the android documentation here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: But is it ok to use activityViewModels in single activity architecture?

Comment: i think it's ok, since this method is used only to get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to fragment's parent Activity